# How to read "variable with backslash from stdin " for bash osx version

Tags: bash, macos

Yet another question about backslash being eaten up inside bash command/script, when the ultimate goal is to change backslash to forward slash.
There are several posts about this in stackoverflow. Most suggest using

```
"read -r"
```

And after playing around with quite a while, I am stuck. I am not sure whether it's a osx issue or bash issue I am hitting up.

However, in my mac bash using the following function

```
slashme () 
{ 
  read -r varname;
  echo "$varname";
  echo "$1"; 
  x="$(echo "$1" | sed 's.\\.\/.g')"; 
  echo "$x"; 
}
```

and the following input

> `slashme "\\my\\precious"`

```
> \my\precious
> 
> /my/precious
```

What I would expect is following :

```
\\my\\precious

//my//precious
```

so, what is the magic switch I am missing ?
I am running
GNU Bash 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin-15)

Comment: Why are you escaping the forward slash in sed?

Comment: Why the `read` to `varname` inside the function? You're not using that variable for anything (but to echo it).

Comment: Just for debugging steps I added the varname to show that reading in the variable, echoing the variable inside double qoutes is not getting me the variable with backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\\` represents a literal backslash in a double-quoted string. Use single quotes:

```
slashme '\\my\\precious'
```

Comment: Is it wrong/not advised to use double-quotes with three slashes?

Comment: It would be four slashes; at this point, it's better to switch to single quotes so that the contents actually look like what you intend. Note that you don't need to escape the second one because `\m` has no special meaning; if it were, say, a dollar sign, you'd need `"\\\\$foo"` instead of `"\\\$foo"`.

Comment: Appreciate the useful information, but on `4.4.12` both `printf` as `printf "%s\n" "\\\my\\\precious"` and `echo` as `echo "\\\my\\\precious"` properly produces 2 slashes

Comment: can I somehow write a function/alias wherein I can just do following: `slashme \\my\precious` i.e. not add the before and after qoutes ? I get a lot of emails with windows network path and I want to make it easy on my to use this bash function without having to worry about the extra qoutes. thanks

Comment: @thassan, not as a regular function, but you could use Bash's readline  features and bind some key to mangle the command line as you're writing it... The question then is what you want to do with the resulting string.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I guess you can call it syntactic sugar. I have tons of alias in my bashrc. I don't want to keep reminding myself that when I use slashme I would need to use single qoutes around the argument. The basic idea is to just pass the string , and let the function take care of doing whatever it needs to for converting the forward to backward slash. But, I can see this would be kind of roundabout way of doing things? thanks

Comment: @thassan, the function doesn't see its command line before the shell parses the quotes and backslashes, so you have to enter the quotes or give  the string to the function some other way.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Bash, you don't even need the `sed`, [Bash can do the string replacement by itself](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

For example:

```
$ slashme() { 
  x=${1//\\/\/}
  echo "$x"; 
}

$ slashme '\\my\\precious'
//my//precious
```

The point about having to quote the string to prevent the backslashes from being treated specially, stands.

If you don't want to add quotes, you could use `read` and enter the string after running the function:

```
$ slashme() { 
    read -r x
    echo "${x//\\/\/}"
}
$ slashme 
\\my\\precious
//my//precious
```

Comment: I would have to take chepner 's answer, since it directly addresses the core of the issue. But in my actual bash script , I am actually using ilkkachu's suggestions of using bash's own regex. So thanks... :)

Answer (score 1):

To *complement* the existing, helpful answers by **addressing the OP's related desire not to have to enter quotes on the command line**:

- As [ikkachu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6372809/ilkkachu) points out, **there is no way around quoting arguments** properly, as **the shell interprets arguments *before* they're passed** on to the target command.
- You can **make *typing* the necessary quotes simpler by defining `readline` macros that insert *pairs* of quotes and place the cursor between them** - see below.

Add the following definitions to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
# Insert paired quotes and place the cursor between them.
# \e is ESC
# \e[D moves the cursor left
"\e\"": "\"\"\e[D"
"\e'": "''\e[D"
```

The next time you open a shell, you'll be able to type <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd> and <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> to insert a pair of single / double quotes and have the cursor placed between them.

Note that you *first* press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and *then* the quote character.

However, terminal applications can be configured to use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd>) key instead, which enables using the faster method of *simultaneously* pressing the macro trigger:

- <kbd>Alt+'</kbd> to insert paired single quotes
- <kbd>Alt+"</kbd> to insert paired double quotes

On macOS, open `Terminal.app`'s preferences, select the profile of interest on the `Profiles` tab, click the `Keyboard` anchor, and select `Use Option as Meta key`; note, however, that this disables the usual, system-wide <kbd>Option</kbd>-based macOS keyboard shortcuts for producing character variations.

Of course, you're free to choose your own key-sequence / key-chord triggers.
See `man bash`, section `READLINE`.